# printing multiple results using, System.out.println

Tags: java

I want to print multiple results from an array but in a more compact way. What I exactly want to know is that,for instance:

```
public class Example {
    public static void main(String[] args) {


String[] myNames = { "A", "B", "C", "D"};
        System.out.println(myNames[1]);
        System.out.println(myNames[2]);
    }
}
```

How can I print both indices 1 and 2, with only one:

```
System.out.println();
```

I've tried putting the two indices right after one another or comma-separated,like:

```
System.out.println([1][2]);
```

or

```
System.out.println([1],[2]);
```

, but they don't work.
And if there'e a compact way for this, what's the general syntax.
Thanks.

Comment: This question is best answered by reading any tutorial on arrays. Don't cheat yourself -- read the tutorial.

Comment: Actually I've just started reading arrays. I'm trying to play around with what I'm learning.

Comment: Attention: Arrays in Java are zero based, so element 1 and 2 is index zero and one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do it with `printf` Java 
printf( )

```
System.out.printf( “format-string” [,arg1, arg2, ... ] ); //%s for string. %d for decimal integer, %c for character.  

System.out.printf("%s\n%s",myNames[1], myNames[2]);
```

or with `println`

```
System.out.println(myNames[1] + "\n" + myNames[2]);
```

for more information you can check this site. https://www.cs.colostate.edu/~cs160/.Spring16/resources/Java_printf_method_quick_reference.pdf

Comment: Thanks Solomon. It worked; and I think I got the syntax.

Answer (score 0):

Java has

> +

to print strings.

> System.out.println(myNames[1] + " " + myNames[2]);

Answer (score -1):

Try this code:

```
for(String names : myNames){System.out.print(names);}
```